# Распараллеливание построения графика matplotlib

Tags: python, многопоточность, matplotlib

Я строю большое количество отрезков на графике mpl и пытаюсь распаралеллить этот процесс. Использую Pool, каждый процесс строит свою порцию отрезков на общей Figure. Но когда я вызываю plt.show() после выполнения всех процессов, получаю чистый график, на котором нет ничего, хотя ожидаю увидеть на нем работу процессов.
Если вызвать plt.show() в дочерних процессах, получится график с отрезками, построенными этим процессом.
Подскажите что я делаю не так, или может есть другой способ ускорить построение большого числа отрезков?

```
def build_plot_tree(ray):

    head = RayTree(ray)
    build_tree(head, ell, 3)
    plot_tree(head, ax) # функция строящая отрезки

    plt.show() # на графике только те отрезки что построил этот процесс

    return


rays = [Ray([5, 5.1, 0.6], [-1, -1, 0]), Ray([5, 4.5, 0.6], [-1, -1, 0])]
ell = Ellipsoid(2, 1.5, 1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.5)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[10, 10])
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
plot_ellipsoid(ell, ax)

ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
ax.set_zlim(-2, 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 3)
    pool.map(build_plot_tree, rays)
    pool.close()
    plt.show() # чистый график, без данных
```

Comment: Что делается внутри вашей функции " plot_tree" мы не видим. Но скорее всего там вы создаете свой объект plt  с которым и работаете. Внутри каждого процесса - со своим.  По окончанию процесса этот объект исчезает вместе с процессом. Вот и оказывается, что plt.show() в __main__ выводит пустой объект. По крайней мере, я бы ковырял в этом направлении.

Comment: plot_tree использует объект ax, который я в него передаю. Если отбросить вычисления то код этой функции что-то вроде ax.plot(...). Больше внутри этой функции я не работаю ни с чем. Вызов pyplot.show показывает все текущие фигуры, если верить документации,  вот я и не понимаю, вроде фигуру создаю одну, передаю её воркерам, они с ней работают. Так почему же не отображаются изменения.

Comment: Похоже, что вы с объектом ax пытаетесь работать как с глобальной переменной. При мультипроцессинге.  При том, что в таком случае вам надо обеспечить, что-бы каждый из процессов начинал работать с объектом тогда, когда другой процесс явным образом закончит  работу с этим же объектом. Иначе будет беда. Семафоры придуманы не зря. А я почти уверен,  что вы их не используете. Вот и получаете кашу. Это - если вообще работаете внутри процессов с ГЛОБАЛЬНЫМ объектом ax. Но кода мы не видим, и что там у вас в действительности есть (а не то, что описываете, как оно вам кажется), угадать не можем.